# How to change a before on hover

Tags: html, css

I have an subnavigation which looks like this:

```
<ul class="subnav">
         <li class="odd"><a href="/angebote/fruhbucherrabatt">Frühbucherrabatt</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="/angebote/last-minutes">Last Minutes</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="/angebote/campingrabatt">Campingrabatt</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="/angebote/junge-familien-rabatt">Junge Familien Rabatt</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="/angebote/55-Plus-Rabatt">55 Plus Rabatt</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="/angebote/ruckkehrrabatt">Rückkehrrabatt</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="/angebote/ruckkehrrabatt">Limitierte Angebote</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Thereby I have my own bullet points like this in css:

```
nav.mainnav ul li .subnav li:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 5px;
 height: 5px;
 background: #000;
 margin-top: 13px;
 left: 6px;
 z-index: 1;
 border-radius: 6px;
}
```

I want to change its content on hover like this:

```
nav.mainnav ul li .subnav li:hover:before {
    content: "»";
}
```

But it is not changing and hiding the "bullet point" but it only adds the double arrow below it. Could someone help me out on this?

Comment: As a side note you're classes "odd and even" could be replaced with `:nth-child(odd), :nth-child(even)` if you're adding odd/even styles FYI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to hide the first bullet, so you need to set `background:none` on `:hover:before` and it works

this is because at first you make the `:before` with `background` and then you want to make the `:before` with `content:""` . so either you set `background:none` on `:hover:before` either you use `content:"•"` at first and then `content:"»"` at hover

**1.** `background:none` on `:hover:before`

```css
.subnav li:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 5px;
 height: 5px;
 background: #000;
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 1;
 border-radius: 6px;
 top:6px;

}

.subnav li:hover:before {
    content: "»";
    background:none;
    top:0px;
}

.subnav li { 
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  padding-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="subnav">
         <li class="odd"><a href="/angebote/fruhbucherrabatt">Frühbucherrabatt</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="/angebote/last-minutes">Last Minutes</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="/angebote/campingrabatt">Campingrabatt</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="/angebote/junge-familien-rabatt">Junge Familien Rabatt</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="/angebote/55-Plus-Rabatt">55 Plus Rabatt</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="/angebote/ruckkehrrabatt">Rückkehrrabatt</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="/angebote/ruckkehrrabatt">Limitierte Angebote</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**2.** `content: "•"` and `content: "»"`

```css
.subnav li:before {
 content: "•";
 position: absolute;
 width: 5px;
 height: 5px;
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 1;
 font-size:15px;
 top:0px;

}

.subnav li:hover:before {
    content: "»";
    top:0px;
}

.subnav li { list-style:none;position:relative;padding-left:15px;}
```

```html
<ul class="subnav">
         <li class="odd"><a href="/angebote/fruhbucherrabatt">Frühbucherrabatt</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="/angebote/last-minutes">Last Minutes</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="/angebote/campingrabatt">Campingrabatt</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="/angebote/junge-familien-rabatt">Junge Familien Rabatt</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="/angebote/55-Plus-Rabatt">55 Plus Rabatt</a></li>
         <li class="even"><a href="/angebote/ruckkehrrabatt">Rückkehrrabatt</a></li>
         <li class="odd"><a href="/angebote/ruckkehrrabatt">Limitierte Angebote</a></li>
 </ul>
```

so you choose between these 2 solutions. let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
li:hover {
    list-style-type: symbols(cyclic "»");
}
```

For something like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
    <li>Bananas</li
</ul>
```

With above, bullet points (default list styling, obviously) are redrawn as `»` when you hover above a list item.